# jung-kurt/gofpdf TM trademark symbol not rendering correctly

Tags: go, pdf, utf-8

```
stringTMSymbol := "™️"
pdf.TransformBegin()
pdf.TransformTranslate(x, y)
pdf.Line(0.0, 0.0, w, 0.0)
pdf.SetXY(0, 0.0)
pdf.SetFont("Arial", "", 14)
pdf.CellFormat(w, 0.33, "URN" + stringTMSymbol, "", 0, "C", false, 0, "")
pdf.Line(0, 0.32, w, 0.32)
pdf.TransformEnd()
```

The code example results in a pdf with unrecognizable characters:

[image]

This should look like:

`URN™️`

I imagine this is a character encoding issue. How can I render a ™️ symbol on pdf using jung-kurt/gofpdf?

Comment: Make sure your source file is in utf8 encoding. Since it's a string literal in the source, a source file encoding problem could cause incorrect output.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: In whatever editor you're using to edit .go files.

Comment: Thats interesting

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with

https://godoc.org/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf#Fpdf.UnicodeTranslatorFromDescriptor

following this example:

https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/issues/6

```
tr := pdf.UnicodeTranslatorFromDescriptor("")
pdf.CellFormat(w, 0.33, "URN" + tr(stringTMSymbol), "", 0, "C", false, 0, "")
```